# Convolution of Gaussian and parabolic function.

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

What is convolution of $\exp(-x^2)$ i.e Gaussian function and $2x^2$? I don't have any idea,as I have found that Laplace transform of Gaussian function involves complementary error function,so inverse Laplace doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: The fourier transform of a gaussian is another gaussian and there is a conolution theorem for fourier transforms, try that.

Comment: yes I know that,but fourier transform of parabola does not exist...as the parabola is not absolutely integrable

Comment: Direct computation would give you an answer. If you want to avoid brutal force, then you may use the fact that $\exp(-x^2) = \sqrt{\pi}f_X(x)$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1/2)$. Then the convolution is given by $$ \int_{\Bbb{R}} 2(x-t)^2e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = 2\sqrt{\pi} \Bbb{E}[(X - t)^2] = 2\sqrt{\pi}(\tfrac{1}{2} + t^2). $$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'standard result', but I can tell you that this is not a hard result once you know the gaussian integral.

Comment: I think I can compute....I will try...it is second moment of X with respect to t...isn't it ?

Comment: It was easy...thanks for the hint, Sir